# How to get notified when NIC card is on or off in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ip

I am trying to add a hook.

The functionality of the hook is to get the notification when a network interface card is on or off. On and off means having an active ip address or not. I don't want to check all the available ip addresses periodically. Instead, can I get notified when this happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I monitor the NIC status(up/down) in a C program without polling the kernel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225888/how-can-i-monitor-the-nic-statusup-down-in-a-c-program-without-polling-the-ker)

Comment: I am looking for a way in the kernel instead of user space

Comment: The final answer for my question is here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988916/how-to-catch-the-nic-interruptup-down